# Disabling a signal in CAPl within 100ms

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I have a scenario where I need to check if signal `sigA` is unavailable for 100ms.
I need it  to set a certain value let's say `13`.

How can I do this in CAPL?

Cyclic time of the message: 10ms.

Comment: Hello Anubha, and welcome to SO. We [encourage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) people to show their efforts before asking for a solution.

Comment: Your signal should always be available. The only reason why it should not be is if the CAN bus shut down. Do you want to check a specific value?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about CAN bus, signals are included in messages. You cannot disable an individual signal, only whole messages. For example, the function `TestDisableMsg` allows you to disable the message sent by the simulation. Check the help for details.